# Computer Architecture – Why are they different even if the machine is the same?

Tags: linux, bash, raspberry-pi, raspbian, cpu-architecture

I've got a Raspberry Pi 4.

If I install NOOBS / Raspbian and run the comand.

`uname -m` I get `armv7l` as an output.

If I install Ubuntu on the very same Pi (same hardware)

Running `uname -m` yields `arm64`.

Why are the outputs different if the hardware is the same? (which I think it's directly related to the hardware)?

Comment: https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=245846

Comment: There is a huge difference between armv7l and arm64.  One is a 32-bit processor the other is a 64-bit processor. This question does not seem well researched.

Comment: I disagree. Installing two different OS's on the same hardware and getting different results I think it's enough research to ask a question on a forum about how to interpret such results to more experienced fellow users; which they seemed to be able to answer with insightful knowledge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like the Raspbian is 32-bit, while Ubuntu is 64-bit.

armv7l/ARMv7 is 32-bit, while arm64/ARMv8 means 64-bit.

A 32-bit operating system places the CPU in 32-bit mode,
so that's what would be detected by a utility such as
`uname --machine`.

Comment: So the conclusion is that `uname` command returns the arch for the OS rather than the underlying hardware? Seems a bit odd as the man page states: `-m, --machine: print the machine hardware name` [Src](https://linux.die.net/man/1/uname)

Comment: I'm not sure how good is a 32-bit OS at detecting a 64-bit architecture.

Comment: @SomerandomITboy  Technically when running in 32bit mode the underlying architecture *is* 32 bit. Most processors run in *either* "32 bit" or "64 bit" (which may have 32bit extensions) and they are distinct modes (architectures) that they work in.

Comment: This was enlightening. Thanks for your notes @Mokubai and harrymc.

Comment: Mokubai's comments were also helpful as well as the comment left under my quesiton. I'll accept the answer but please add such comments in it for reference.

Comment: @SomerandomITboy yes that man page is odd. To get the hardware architecture you need to `cat /proc/cpuinfo`